# Issue in SharePoint modern document library choice columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type, site-column

I have multi-choice site column required field, whenever tried to upload the document by default it auto-populates the three choice values even if i removed the choice values and kept only one value in the choice column.

I don't know why its happening like it. But when I change the choice column values and set the value then it resets with only single value from the choice column which is right.

Please advise me on this.

Comment: Can you check the site column settings, is there any default value set in column settings? Also, this issue is for only one user or all users in SharePoint site?

Comment: For all users in SharePoint. Also, there is no default value set in the choice column. I think  its bug.

Comment: Are the uploaded documents all based off the same template? Is it possible that the template has the three choice values populated? Can you try creating a brand new document on your desktop and see what happens when you upload that?

Comment: Do other lists have this problem? Or do other sites have this problem?